# How to convert JSO to JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have example :

```
var data = [{"name":"eric","age":"24"},{"name":"goulding","age":"23"}]
```

I want to convert jso above to json like this result :

```
[{name:"eric",age:24},{name:"goulding",age:23}]
```

Please give me advice.

Comment: What you've provided isn't JSON, it's simply a JSO.

Comment: Haha JSO! I gonna use it!

Comment: Please confirm that your data is actually just a JavaScript object, and not a JSON string. Also, please change the title of the question to something meaningful.

Comment: @torazaburo Thank you, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) with a reviver parameter:

```
var jsonString = '[{"name":"eric","age":"24"},{"name":"goulding","age":"23"}]';

// given a string value, returns the number representation
// if possible, else returns the original value
var reviver = function (key, value) {
    var number = Number(value);

    return number === number ? number : value;
};

// because the reviver parameter is provided,
// the parse process will call it for each key-value pair
// in order to determine the ultimate value in a set
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString, reviver);
```

When the reviver is called with `reviver("name", "eric")`, it returns `"eric"` because `"eric"` cannot be converted to a number. However when called with `reviver("age", "24")`, the number `24` is returned.

Meanwhile, as others already noted the literal `[{"name":"eric","age":"24"},{"name":"goulding","age":"23"}]` is **not** JSON, it is an array. But the string `'[{"name":"eric","age":"24"},{"name":"goulding","age":"23"}]'` represents a valid JSON formatted array object.

Comment: This might be a good solution **if** the OP was actually starting off with a JSON string, but there are no real indications that that is the ase.

Comment: Would there be any need to convert an object to an object? The question is not skillfully worded, but if one really put some consideration into it one could read ***How to convert JSON String... to Object JavaScript?***. We all probably can infer the OP's intention.

Comment: We can equally infer that he actually doesn't know what JSON is, and thinks a JS object is JSON like many other people. That is supported by the fact that he did not show a quoted string in his question. It also seems a bit hard to imagine that someone has never even heard of `JSON.parse`. It's more likely that he somehow wants to "convert" strings into numbers. Bottom line, we don't know until the OP wakes up and answers the clarifying comment.

Comment: Your comments are sound.

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = [{"name":"eric","age":"24"},{"name":"goulding","age":"23"}]
```

This is JSON and in order to convert it to a JavaScript object (jso) we need to use `parse`. If we want to manipulate JSON, we convert JSON to JSO using `JSON.parse`.

```
let convertedToJSO = JSON.parse(data)
```

```
let data = [{name:"eric",age:24},{name:"goulding",age:23}]
```

And this is a JSO. If you want to print or save JSO, convert JSO to JSON using `JSON.stringfy`.

```
let convertedToJSO = JSON.stringfy(data)
```